# Horizontal Barplot in R for paper

Tags: r, plot

I'm writing a dissertation and I'd like to construct a "professional" horizontal barplot.
It should seem something like this in terms of the layout, but the colors are not appropriate for formal writing:
[image]

Let me make a simple example on how I tried to code it:

```
df=data.frame(Country=c("USA","DEU","CHN","ITA","JPN"), Stock=c(1000,500,15000,300,600))
y=df$Country
x=df$Stock
barplot(y~x,horiz=TRUE)
```

The problem is that not all the countries are displayed on the y-axis and how can I make the stock number values appear to the right of the bar as per the picture above?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput` and code you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read `?barplot`, function has many nice features. For the country labels use a named vector `a` to avoid confusing the allocations. The bar labels can be done with `text`.

```
pdf('plot.pdf', width=12, height=4)

par(mar=c(5, 8, 4, 6))
a <- setNames(c('United States', 'Germany', 'China', 'Italy', 'Japan'), df$Country)
b <- barplot(df$Stock, horiz=TRUE, names.arg=a[df$Country], xlab='\'000 of units',
             col=4, border=4, axes=F, 
             main='Annual installations of industrial robots\n15 largest markets 2019')
## bar labels
text(df$Stock + 100, b, labels=df$Stock/1e3, adj=0, xpd=TRUE, col=4)
## special x axis
mtext(axTicks(1)/1e3, 1, 1, at=axTicks(1))

dev.off()
```

The dimensions of the plot, and thus bar widths can be controlled by `width` and `height` parameters of `pdf` device. Check journal guide which format is needed. Find your plot in your working directory (use `getwd()`).

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(Country = c("USA", "DEU", "CHN", "ITA", "JPN"), 
    Stock = c(1000, 500, 15000, 300, 600)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following code:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(country = c('China', 'Japan', 'United States'),
                 value = c(140.5, 49.9, 33.3))
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(country, value), y = value)) +
  geom_col(fill = 'Sky Blue') +
  geom_text(aes(label = value), color = 'Sky Blue', hjust = -0.1) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(10), limits = c(0, 160)) +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x = '', y = bquote("'000 of units"), title = 'Annual installations of industrial robots \n 15 largest markets 2019') +
  theme_grey() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.length = unit(0, "points"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>